# How would/do I access/program a remote Arduino through SSH via an intermediate computer?

Tags: linux, ssh, arduino

I have Arduino IDE installed on my laptop and I'd like to program a remote Arduino (Uno) that is connected to a remote machine in the same network, say, for instance, a Raspberry Pi (to which the Arduino Uno would be plugged with the USB cable) connected to my wireless network. What would I need to set up to do that?

Note: I don't mean to use the Arduino as a SSH client. What I'd like to do is some kind of tunnelling, preferably SSH, between Arduino IDE on my laptop and the Raspberry PI, to which the Arduino board is connected with the USB cable.

Ideally what would happen when I press the `Upload` button is that the firmware, compiled locally would then be sent to the remote Arduino through the tunnel. Also I would use the serial monitor to remotely connect to the `/dev/ttyACM0` device node on the remote Pi.

Comment: Can you install `avrdude` on the rpi?

Comment: You might look at [usbip](https://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-set-up-a-usb-over-ip-server-and-client-with-ubuntu-10.04) to make the remote usb device appear local to your laptop.

Comment: @thrig Didn't mention it but sure, I can install avrdude on it.

Comment: @meuh I didn't know about `usbip`, definitely worth taking a look! Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lacking a usb device proxy (usbip as of Feb 2016 does not appear to be very portable) another method is to install `avrdude` on the Arduino-connected system (REMOTE). If this is possible, then the Arduino IDE running system (CLIENT) can be instructed to call a program that connects to `avrdude` on REMOTE. Downsides: requires fiddling around in the Arduino IDE configuration files, probably fragile, will require additional work to support things like `arduinoOTA` and so on...

```
CLIENT (Arduino IDE) -> ssh -> REMOTE (avrdude) -> usb -> arduino
```

The Arduino IDE should contain `programmers.txt` and `platform.txt` configuration files (located for example under `Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware/arduino/avr` on the mac version). What we need in these files is a new programmer that will make a connection to REMOTE and pass along the data to upload, and then on REMOTE to issue the actual `avrdude` programmer command using the data passed from the CLIENT system.

### CLIENT programmer

In `Java/hardware/arduino/avr/programmers.txt` add something like

```
avrrelay.name=AVR RELAY
avrrelay.protocol=stk500v2
avrrelay.program.tool=avrrelay
avrrelay.program.extra_params=
```

More complicatedly, in `Java/hardware/arduino/avr/platform.txt` duplicate all the `tools.avrdude.` containing lines and adjust these to instead be named `tools.avrrelay.` and where necessary instead call `avrrelay-client` (most of these lines are not necessary but it's probably easier to sub all of them than to figure out which are necessary):

```
tools.avrrelay.path={runtime.tools.avrdude.path}
tools.avrrelay.cmd.path={path}/bin/avrrelay-client
tools.avrrelay.config.path={path}/etc/avrdude.conf
... many more of these not shown, e.g. the verbose one ...
tools.avrrelay.upload.pattern="{cmd.path}" "{build.path}/{build.project_name}.hex"
tools.avrrelay.program.pattern="{cmd.path}" "{build.path}/{build.project_name}.hex"
```

Then in the `Java/hardware/tools/avr/bin` directory (which should be identical to the `runtime.tools.avrdude.path` config option) create `avrrelay-client` and make it executable:

```
#!/bin/sh
# send the only argument (which should be the *.hex file) to avrrelay-remote
# this will need to use public key auth, or expect to automatically fill
# in any password promptes
ssh theremotehost avrrelay-remote < "$1"
```

### REMOTE script

The Arduino IDE has a preference option to show verbose output during the upload, which will reveal the command that is run.

```
/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avrdude \
-C/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware/tools/avr/etc/avrdude.conf \
-v -patmega328p -cstk500v2 -Pusb \
-Uflash:w:/blablabla.../Blink.ino.hex:i
```

This command can be copied and adapted for the code on REMOTE, though `avrdude(1)` indicates that a filename must be specified, so the copied data will need to be placed in a tmp file, and that fed to `avrdude`; this is the `avrrelay-remote` program called by the CLIENT; it will need to be `chmod +x` and called by full path or located in a SSH-available `PATH` directory.

```
#!/bin/sh
FLASH=`mktemp /tmp/avrrelay.XXXXXXXXXX` || exit 1
# assume data passed via standard input
cat > "$FLASH"
# these flags will vary depending on programmer, etc
avrdude -C /path/to/avrdude.conf -v -patmega328p -cstk500v2 -Pusb \
"-Uflash:w:$FLASH:i"
```

In theory, restart the Arduino IDE and try using the new "AVR RELAY" programmer. Use your mad debugging skills to figure out where it breaks down, repeat.

### remote serial monitor

For the serial monitor to work remotely, a likely option would be to forward that via `socat`:

[Unbuffered socat command to connect serial ports in remote machines and log the data](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/321799/unbuffered-socat-command-to-connect-serial-ports-in-remote-machines-and-log-the)

Comment: Thanks **a lot** for this detailed procedure. I'll test it and report my findings.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest setup would be to install the Arduino IDLE on the remote computer and then use ssh to access that.

To be able to send graphics over ssh, just add the flag -X to the end:

```
$ ssh username@ip-adress -X
```

Answer (score 1):

If the underlying goal is to program the Arduino without having to disconnect it from a pre-existing USB connection (e.g. perhaps its a node on a ROS system), but you are physically close enough to it to run a cable, you could just use an in-system programmer (I use an Olimex AVI-ISP-MK2) on the ICSP port.

In the Arduino IDE it's Sketch > Upload Using Programmer, or Ctrl+Shift+U. It's even easier doing it this way than over USB because the /dev assignment for the USB port that the ISP's connected to never needs to be set.

~Justine

Answer (score 0):

The answer by thrig is very detailed, but kept general. I thought it might be helpful to also have an answer that is almost cut and paste. The following is tested with Arduino IDE 1.8.12 on Windows 10 1903, but should be easy to adapt to older Windows versions if you supply your own scp and ssh.

For this to work, you need to set up things such that you can ssh from *local* to *remote* without being asked for a password or passphrase on the command line.

It also assumes that you have successfully set up and configured the Arduino IDE with avrdude on the remote system.

In all of the following, you need to modify anything marked by ***

Final disclaimer: I haven't tested what happens if any of the paths contain spaces. Also, there are no checks to prevent you from overwriting files or the like.

On the local system, in ***Arduino-Installation-Dir***\hardware\arduino\avr create or edit a file called

*platform.local.txt* and add this as content:

```
tools.remoteavrdude.path={runtime.tools.avrdude.path}
tools.remoteavrdude.cmd.path={path}\bin\avrrelay.bat
tools.remoteavrdude.remote.host=***user***@***host***
tools.remoteavrdude.remote.cmd.path=***how to invoke avrdude on the remote system. could be sudo avrdude***
tools.remoteavrdude.remote.config.path=***which config file on the remote system to use. could be /etc/avrdude.conf***
tools.remoteavrdude.remote.file.path=***to which filename the compiled code should be copied to on the remote system***

tools.remoteavrdude.upload.params.verbose=-v
tools.remoteavrdude.upload.params.quiet=-q -q
# tools.remoteavrdude.upload.verify is needed for backwards compatibility with IDE 1.6.8 or older, IDE 1.6.9 or newer overrides this value
tools.remoteavrdude.upload.verify=
tools.remoteavrdude.upload.params.noverify=-V
tools.remoteavrdude.upload.pattern="{cmd.path}" {remote.host} "{remote.cmd.path} -C{remote.config.path} {upload.verbose} {upload.verify} ***the board-specific options*** -Uflash:w:{remote.file.path}:i" {build.path}\{build.project_name}.hex {remote.file.path}

tools.remoteavrdude.program.params.verbose=-v
tools.remoteavrdude.program.params.quiet=-q -q
# tools.remoteavrdude.program.verify is needed for backwards compatibility with IDE 1.6.8 or older, IDE 1.6.9 or newer overrides this value
tools.remoteavrdude.program.verify=
tools.remoteavrdude.program.params.noverify=-V
tools.remoteavrdude.program.pattern="{cmd.path}" {remote.host} "{remote.cmd.path} -C{remote.config.path} {program.verbose} {program.verify} ***the board-specific options*** -Uflash:w:{remote.file.path}:i" {build.path}\{build.project_name}.hex {remote.file.path}

tools.remoteavrdude.erase.params.verbose=-v
tools.remoteavrdude.erase.params.quiet=-q -q
tools.remoteavrdude.erase.pattern="{cmd.path}" {remote.host} "{remote.cmd.path} -C{config.path} {erase.verbose} {program.extra_params} -e ***the board-specific options*** -Ulock:w:{bootloader.unlock_bits}:m -Uefuse:w:{bootloader.extended_fuses}:m -Uhfuse:w:{bootloader.high_fuses}:m -Ulfuse:w:{bootloader.low_fuses}:m"

tools.remoteavrdude.bootloader.params.verbose=-v
tools.remoteavrdude.bootloader.params.quiet=-q -q
tools.remoteavrdude.bootloader.pattern="{cmd.path}" {remote.host} "{remote.cmd.path} -C{config.path} {bootloader.verbose} ***the board-specific options*** {program.extra_params} -Uflash:w:{remote.file.path}:i -Ulock:w:{bootloader.lock_bits}:m {runtime.platform.path}\bootloaders\{bootloader.file} {remote.file.path}
```

For ***the board specific options***, check *platform.txt* on the remote system. Usually something like `-p{build.mcu} -c{upload.protocol} -D` for upload and `-p{build.mcu} -c{protocol} {program.extra_params}` else

Also in this directory, edit

*programmers.txt* and add the following content:

```
remoteavrdude.name=remote avrdude
remoteavrdude.protocol=***what your board needs***
remoteavrdude.program.tool=remoteavrdude
***any other options for your board and programmer, check programmers.txt on the remote system***
```

Then, in ***Arduino-Installation-Dir***\hardware\tools\avr\bin create a file called

*avrrelay.bat* and add this as content:

```
IF "%~3" == "" GOTO execute
C:\Windows\Sysnative\OpenSSH\scp.exe "%3" %1:%4
:execute
C:\Windows\Sysnative\OpenSSH\ssh.exe %1 %2
```

If you are using some other scp / ssh, change the paths above.